# Converting String to Date before submitting MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, string, date, post

I've been trying to convert a string date into a date field in MySQL.
It is more user friendly on the client side to submit as a string.

Here's what I have so far on the php side:

```
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$dateofdeath = $_POST['dateofdeath'];
$date = STR_TO_DATE('$dateofdeath','%d,%m,%Y');
$sql = "INSERT INTO FRSLNamelist (fullname,dateofdeath) VALUES ('$fullname','$date')";
```

I'm getting - `Fatal error: Call to undefined function STR_TO_DATE()`

both fields are submitted as text.

I have had a good search of google and stackoverflow, but they are mostly to do with query and convert rather than convert then submit.

Cheers to anyone that can help.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` is a MySQL function, you are using it in PHP

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** put `$_POST` data directly in your query. This is completely reckless and will get you into serious trouble because you've created a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) due to not [escaping things properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code

Convert the string to a timestamp date.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$timestamp = strtotime($_POST['dateofdeath']);
$date=date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
$sql = "INSERT INTO FRSLNamelist (fullname,dateofdeath) VALUES ('$fullname','$date')";
```

Comment: Still get the same error.
I don't need a time so i want to avoid using the string to time function.

Comment: You can change the format in which date is stored use date('Y-m-d') and avoid H:i:s because it is the format of time.

Comment: ** This is what is coming back:**

`Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Australia/Perth' for 'WST/8.0/no DST' instead`


`Fatal error: Function name must be a string`

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('UTC');   Add this code at the beginning of the code and check whether itz working or not.